# $A$ is a square matrix of order $2$ with real entries and ${\rm Tr}(A)+|A|=2$. Show that $|A^2+|A|\cdot A+{\rm Tr}(A)I_2|\geq 4$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, trace, cayley-hamilton

$A$ is a square matrix of order $2$ with real entries and ${\rm Tr}(A)+|A|=2$. Show that

$$|A^2+|A|\cdot A+{\rm Tr}(A)I_2|\geq 4$$

**My Attempt**

I could observe that ${\rm Tr}(A)+|A|=2\Rightarrow 1+a+d+ad-bc=3 \Rightarrow|A+I|=3$

By Cayley-Hamilton theorem for a $2\times 2$ matrix we have

$A^2-{\rm Tr}(A)\cdot A+|A|\cdot I_2=0$.

$A^2={\rm Tr}(A)\cdot A-|A|\cdot I_2$

So $A^2+|A|\cdot A+{\rm Tr}(A)I_2={\rm Tr}(A)\cdot A-|A|\cdot I_2+|A|\cdot A+{\rm Tr}(A)I_2$

$=({\rm Tr}(A)+|A|)A+({\rm Tr}(A)-|A|)I_2$

$=2A+({\rm Tr}(A)-|A|)I_2=2A+2(1-|A|)I_2$

$|A^2+|A|\cdot A+{\rm Tr}(A)I_2|=4|A+(1-|A|)I_2|$

Not able to proceed from here. I am wondering whether Cayley Hamilton was the right approach or not.

Answer (score 3):

***Maybe not the shortest solution, but it works :***

By Cayley Hamilton, one has
$$A^2 = \mathrm{Tr}(A)A-|A|I_2$$

One deduce that \begin{align*} A^2+|A|.A+\mathrm{Tr}(A)I_2 &= \mathrm{Tr}(A)A-|A|I_2+|A|.A+\mathrm{Tr}(A)I_2 \\
&= (\mathrm{Tr}(A)+|A|)A +(\mathrm{Tr}(A)-|A|)I_2 \quad \quad \quad (*)
\end{align*}

By assumption, one has also $\mathrm{Tr}(A)+|A|=2$, so $(*)$ becomes
\begin{align*} A^2+|A|.A+\mathrm{Tr}(A)I_2 &= 2A +  2(\mathrm{Tr}(A)-1)I_2 
\end{align*}

In particular, using the fact that $|\lambda I_2 + A|=|A|+\lambda\mathrm{Tr}(A)+\lambda^2$, you get
\begin{align*}\big| A^2+|A|.A+\mathrm{Tr}(A)I_2 \big| &= 4\big|(\mathrm{Tr}(A)-1)I_2 + A \big| \\
& =4\left(|A| + (\mathrm{Tr}(A)-1)\mathrm{Tr}(A) + (\mathrm{Tr}(A)-1)^2  \right) \\
& =4\left(|A| + 2\mathrm{Tr}(A)^2-3\mathrm{Tr}(A)+1  \right) \\
& = 4\left(2\mathrm{Tr}(A)^2-4\mathrm{Tr}(A)+3  \right) \quad \quad \textit{using again }\mathrm{Tr}(A)+|A|=2\\
& = 4\left(1 + 2(\mathrm{Tr}(A)-1)^2  \right) \\
& \geq 4
\end{align*}